# How to wake up a sleeping thread in mac

Tags: multithreading, cocoa

I am new to Objective C. I am putting a thread to sleep using

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0f];
```

but when particular events occurs I want to wake up this sleeping thread. How do I wake up this sleeping thread?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very sparse question.  Can you edit it to provide some code samples?  How is the thread sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. If a thread sleeps using that method it cannot be woken until the time is over.

Something like this could be emulated using a `NSCondition` object.

Comment: Never say never... `sleepForTimeInterval` probably calls `nanosleep`, and that will return before the time period expires if a signal occurs, and you can always set things up so the signal has no effect other than to terminate the sleep. However, your answer is probably the best one in the given context - it can't be done in Cocoa alone.

Comment: It might use `nanosleep` or something else that is not interruptible. Since it is not documented it can change any time, so this is not an option at all.

Comment: User-level process sleep on Mach/Unix is interruptible, just like other system calls. Indeed changing this would not make sense at all, a process can be killed at anytime and cannot avoid death by "hiding" in a sleep! So it surely doesn't really matter whether `sleepForTimeInterval` uses `nanosleep` (it does) or not, sleep itself is interruptible. So its a, let's say, obscure option. But as I said, I wouldn't recommend this as an answer to this question, it's just a tidbit for the terminally curious :-)

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. It was just an idea i was tinkering on. What I wanted was to put a thread to sleep(or pause actually) for a period of x seconds and at the same time check if an event has occurred and if an event occurred then continue the thread. If no event has occurred then wait for x seconds and time out.      

The workaround that I used for now is as follows.

Comment: I made a while loop and put the thread to sleep for 1 second. After one second I wake up check to see if the event was triggered. If an event occurred then exit the while loop if not decrement the count of the time and go back in the loop and sleep. Its not the best but it would do.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the use of `NSTimer` over the use of NSThread, mainly due to the limitations of execution control of a sleeping thread. `NSTimer` allows immediate cancellation, via a call to `invalidate`, which could be called in response to some user cancellation. `NSTimer` provides two types of firing: repeating and non-repeating. The code below uses an `NSTimer` to make repeated calls to a specified selector:

```
//delayInSeconds and intervalInSeconds are NSTimeInterval values calclulated elsewhere
NSDate *fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:delayInSeconds];

//Create a timer that will repeat, starting with the fireDate
//Optionally, userInfo could contain an object. checkSomething:
//  would take one parameter, the NSTimer which would carry the userInfo
//timer is a strong property defined for a particular class, as an instance variable.
self.timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate
                                      interval:intervalInSeconds
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(checkSomething:)
                                      userInfo:nil
                                       repeats:TRUE];

//Launch the timer on the main run loop
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

**Limitations of Sleeping an NSThread**

One clear disadvantage of sleeping a thread is that waking it up is such an unconventional solution (involving the use of a signal to kill the process), that one of the only options left is to use a flag. This is a problem because there will be a delay for significant sleep times. For instance, if a sleep time is 10 seconds, then there could be as much as a 10 second delay before the flag is read, and the application responds.

Since `sleepForTimeInterval` is a class method, it is not possible to call `cancel` on the sleeping thread.